# Unable to capture HTTPS traffic in Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, https, fiddler

This probably has been asked before, but I couldn't find relevant information and this is the first time it happens to me. Trying to capture/decrypt traffic from ASP.NET web application. Web.config modified accordingly to point to Fiddler as a proxy:

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
      <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This has worked many times before, but this time Fiddler cannot decrypt HTTPS traffic, getting this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 08:10:40.453
Connection: close
EndTime: 08:10:40.547
ClientToServerBytes: 432
ServerToClientBytes: 3286

This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
Fiddler's HTTPS Decryption feature is enabled, but this specific tunnel was configured not to be decrypted. Settings can be found inside Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS.

A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
SessionID:      54 87 1E 5C 03 C7 16 81 E6 25 E8 8F 48 C0 42 52 23 B6 5B 04 4F 4D 69 67 11 F2 9E 09 D0 27 77 2D
Random:         54 87 1F 00 0D 37 FF 22 3E 6A 10 BF 4D 4F 67 ED C2 D2 97 A9 66 B2 CF 56 0D 8C 7C E5 6B 2E 2E A1
Cipher:         TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA [0x002F]
CompressionSuite:       NO_COMPRESSION [0x00]
Extensions:
renegotiation_info      00
```

Any idea what is going on here and how to make Fiddler decrypt traffic?

Comment: Found this discussion and might help you to narrow down the problem you are facing with Fiddler https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/u3MiFPBOzBo

Comment: @Sam thanks for the link, it didn't help my problem (antivirus is running on the server, but the process displayed in Fiddler is w3p) but I will browse the group and post the question there as well.

Comment: No worries. But, I'm curious now. W3p is the IIS worker process but shouldn't it be browser traffic as suggested in this link?

Comment: @Sam the solution applies to whichever app you're tracing traffic from. In my case ASP.NET app makes HTTPS call from the server-side, so I am tracing that.

Comment: Your certificate generator isn't working. Your question is under discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/ALyM0Iq1slU

Comment: That discussion doesn't fix it for me.